# robot_localization: how to define f function

Tags: ros, navigation, extended-kalman-filter, robot-localization, ekf-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

I'm using and studying the [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) package in order to integrate it with my system. At the moment, I would like to better understand how it works and so I've read the Thomas Moore's [article](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/robot_localization/html/_downloads/robot_localization_ias13_revised.pdf) and I also watched the [video](https://vimeo.com/142624091) presentation.

Unfortunately, I can't understand how the function ***f*** is described in the following relation:
[image: image description]

How it is possible to mathematically define the function ***f*** and ***Q***?

Can you help me in understanding this, please?
I know it's maths and that it is not related to ROS, but I think that it is very important to understand these functions for me.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245871/robot_localization:-how-to-define-f-function/) by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2016-10-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2016-10-17**:
I've read this [topic](http://answers.ros.org/question/221837/robot_localization-ekf-internal-motion-model/), but I would like to have an example on how to write the full ***f*** function, if possible.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2016-10-17**:
May be, I've found the state transition matrix described in this [way](http://campar.in.tum.de/twiki/pub/Chair/KalmanFilter/processmodel_position.jpg). But I can only see 9 components for the vector and not 12 as specified in the article. Why?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-12-19**:
An EKF is estimating the state of something. It's up to the author to determine which variables to estimate. The link you provided is just estimating a different set of variables. Specifically, it appears to lack orientation and angular velocity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This would be a good question for the [Robotics Stack Exchange](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/). Briefly, the function ***f*** is a vector-valued function that takes as its input the entire state *vector* **x_t-1**, and outputs a state vector **x_t**. In this case, even though it's a single function in the paper, we can really express it as a set of functions like this:

```
X = X + X_velocity * time_delta + X_acceleration * 0.5 * time_delta^2
```

```
Y = Y + Y_velocity * time_delta + Y_acceleration * 0.5 * time_delta^2
```

...etc. The only difference from what I have written here is that we have to rotate both the velocities and accelerations by the robot's orientation, since those quantities are given in the robot's body frame.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2016-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0